# Quadripole paradox?

Tags: passive-networks

There must be something fundamental I am missing about two-port quadripoles and network theory. I tried to devise the simplest possible example to clarify what is my problem. Here it comes.

**The paradox**. Look at the trivial network below and its description using the z-impedance parameters.[image]

This seems wrong to me. In the original network, there is a well-defined relationship between the voltage references at two ports, which is completely lost in the z-parameter description where the two ports are floating. I do not think this can be a genuinely equivalent circuit: to me, it just cannot work and I expect problems.

To show where issues can arise, consider the feedback configuration below:

[image]

Consider now the scheme on the left. R3 is shorted and disappears from any equation, R is placed in parallel to R1. The current I feed from the battery is partitioned between R and R1 according to

```
R1*I1 = R*I2,
```

very trivial. Now consider the same situation in the *allegedly* equivalent z-parameter network. We clearly have two equations

```
V = RS*I1+R2*I2
V = (R+R2)*I2+R2*I1
```

If you now equate the two lines you get

```
(R1+R3)*I1 = R*I2
```

... but that's wrong: this is an inconsistent partitioning and anyway R3 is out of the game here. I cannot find any error in my derivation. Rather, I find it not surprising since the z-parameter network does *not* seem to be really equivalent to the original circuit.

**Any clue?** Basically, here I am tempted to conclude that quadripole theory with non-shorted references is ill-defined. How is that possible?! I can't believe it. There must be another explanation. Can you help? Or is this feedback configuration I used "forbidden", in some sense? But then when can I trust the theory? Of course I can implement that feedback configuration in practice.

PS note I have no problem with tripoles, no shortfalls there. I think the problem is specifically related to two-port networks where the reference of V1 and V2 is *not* a trivial short (and then the quadripole is basically a tripole). Maybe I am just missing something.

---

**Edit.** Ok I think I have found some clues (also thanks to hints by user233751!). I leave a comment here for future reference, in case someone gets stuck on the same issue. It looks like - simply - not all connections are "allowed" and so, generally, speaking, the quadripole is *not fully equivalent to the original circuit*. I have landed on something called [Brune Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brune_test), that allows formally checking if a specific combination of ports is allowed or not:

> The Brune test (named after the South African mathematician Otto Brune) is used to check the permissibility of the combination of two or more two-port networks (or quadripoles) in electrical circuit analysis. The test determines whether the network still meets the port condition after the two-ports have been combined. The test is a sufficient, but not necessary, test.

and later on, I found more clues in further works: [IEEE - On Brune's Tests](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/261718933_On_Brune%27s_Tests).

Wow... I am surprised anyway.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be lost when treating a circuit as 2 ports rather than 4 terminals. Treatment as ports implies that connections like this are irrelevant to you.

Comment: Ok, thanks!
I see, but my problem is, formally speaking, what does it mean "connections like this"? For instance, Millmann presents the z-parameters as an apparently generic description of quadripoles (and I am not aware of any extension), and no clear limitation of the use of the model is given. Finding one counterexample is to me alarming... then when does the theory hold? How can I know that in a complex feedback circuit I am not introducing a "wrong" connection "like this" one? Maybe there is no clear answer, but then I would be very surprised since these models are in all books...

Comment: I **think** the "port" abstraction requires balanced current, among possibly other things

Comment: Ah ok I see, this is a good point. This circuit is indeed breaking that condition. Seem hard to tell in general if a generic configuration will break current balancing at the ports or not anyway...